# Server access problem because of DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, opendns

i have a web site and if i use these dns addres 195.175.39.40 and 195.175.39.39(they are default dns addresses in my country's isp), i can't reach my web sit but if i use opendns or googledns i can access to my web site(btgmaslak.com). What should i do ? This is very important thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [whois](http://www.whois.net/whois/btgmaslak.com), a change was made to your DNS today. When did you add the A record for www.btgmaslak.com? If it was just today then you just have to wait for things to propagate - can take up to 48 hours and sometimes even 72.

Comment: yes i updated today. i can wait but Is my dns configuration true ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish with your DNS but there is a valid A record for www.btgmaslak.com so once propagation completes, that should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The domain checks out OK using online DNS tools. The only noteworthy warning was:

It seems you don't have MX records. This means that all the emails sent to your domain will be sent to the A record of your domain (if present), accordingly to RFC 2821 section "5. Address Resolution and Mail Handling".

Checked on: http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/domain_check.php

DNS does not update instantaneously and your regions DNS servers may be taking longer to update than google or OpenDNS. If you made changes within the last 24h, it's likely that it simply hasn't propogated to the regional DNS yet. In which case, you have to wait.